# Encapsulating logging and throwing exceptions into a method. Bad practice?

Tags: java, logging

original code example

```
if (var1 == null) {
    String msg = "var 1 is null";
    logger.log(msg);
    throw new CustomException(msg);
}
if (var2 == null) {
    String msg = "var 2 is null";
    logger.log(msg);
    throw new CustomException(msg);
}
if (var3 == null) {
    String msg = "var 3 is null";
    logger.log(msg);
    throw new CustomException(msg);
}
return var3.toString(); // ok
```

new code

```
if (var1 == null) {
    logMessageAndThrowException("var 1 is null");
}
if (var2 == null) {
    logMessageAndThrowException("var 2 is null");
}
if (var3 == null) {
    logMessageAndThrowException("var 3 is null");
}
return var3.toString(); // NetBeans warn me here for a NPE

void logMessageAndThrowException(String msg) throws CustomException {
    logger.log(msg);
    throw new CustomException(msg);
}
```

Is this a bad practice or NetBeans just are not able to understand the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second version removes some duplication, so it's better, but usually you should choose one of logging and rethrowing. Frameworks/appservers usually catch and log uncatched exceptions so you will have two (or more) entries for the same exception it the log file which makes debugging hard.

> Log the exception only once!
>
> One of the common pain points that I have noticed is logging and
>   rethrowing an exception. As a result, the log files contains the same
>   exceptions several times on several stack levels.

Author: [Nayaki](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/112625/36726)

Comment: youre right... the best thing is probably only throw the exception and let it be logged somewhere else

Comment: +1 for palacsint. First, in the spirit of "separation of concerns", have a separate entity for logging and another separate one for exception throwing. Also, the logging and message throwing invocation could be invoked from inside a loop with the argument's number as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (var3 == null) {
    logMessageAndThrowException("var 3 is null");
}
return var3.toString(); // NetBeans warn me here for a NPE
```

Netbeans probably does not look into the method. Netbeans does not know from the name, what a human will read. So Netbeans sees an if statement, no direct return or throw and assumes that it could happen to execute `return var3.toString();`

In general for arguments checking:

- I would avoid custom exceptions, use runtime exceptions
- I would only check arguments if they are used as a state variable for later usage. If not, it is completely fine to get a direct NullPointer exception. Because the results are the same: I will get a notice about the variable unexpectedly being null at the moment.
- I would use a wrapper/proxy method like:

#

```
public static <T> T notNull(final T value) {
    if (value == null) //you could add more logic here, like logging
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value is null");
    return value;
}
public static <T> T notNull(final T value, final String message) {
    if (value == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value is null, " + message);
    return value;
}
```

to write such code:

```
this.variable = notNull(variable);
```